# Microsoft Exchnage SMTP AUTH using client credentials flow

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, smtp, office365

I could able to access mailbox using IMAP protocol and client credentials flow but if I try to send mail then it got failed with exception:

```
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [PN2PR01CA0190.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-04-10T11:36:49.717Z 08DB38497E3FD62E]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
```

I am sure that on Azure app I have added `SMTP.SendAsApp` permission and admin grant is also given to the permission. Also by using power shell I have also given mailbox permission to application's service principle with access rights as `FullAccess`.

After little bit googling about the problem, I come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558889/azure-ad-service-principal-client-credentials-grant-authenticate-failed-accessin?rq=3), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543343/office365-smtp-with-oauth2-client-credentials-flow-returns-authentication-unsuc) and even some post from Microsoft mentions that [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange) states that SMTP + client credentials flow is not supported but now I visit the URL then there is nothing any such thing mentioned by Microsoft, which is creating confusing state, whether I am doing something wrong that's why getting above exception or still SMTP with client credentials flow is not supported?